# Change Active Directory user password

Tags: windows, passwords, active-directory, password-management

I own an Active Directory user with no access to system resources that is needed to change password.

Is there any easy way to achieve this even if I have no admin rights on Active Directory by just knowing the user's credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Without admin rights, you must be logged in as that specific user in order to change their password.
Once logged in there are several ways for you to change it. I usually instruct them to press ctrl-alt-del and select "change password" from the menu.

Comment: You mean log-in in any AD joined machine? Can this be done even if the users has no access on any machine?

Comment: For a simple user account, that user can log into any machine that is joined to the domain. Once logged in, that same user can change their password.    If you have a user account that is denied the right to log in, then only an admin can change the password for that account.